# Use a pointer to enter strings from a file into a 2D char array in C

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers, char

I'm having trouble inputting strings from a file into my 2D char array (string array). I need to do it with pointers, however, it produces a weird jumble of the last and second to last words. Also, I cannot use the string library functions.

Here is my code so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    FILE *fin, *fout;
    char lineRead[20], arr2[20][20];
    int i, j, k, len;


    fin = fopen("cp4in_1.txt","r");
    if (fin){
        while(fscanf(fin,"%s",&lineRead) != EOF){
            char *pointer = lineRead;
            for (k = 0; lineRead[k] != '\0'; k++);
            for (i = 0; i < 4; i++){
                for (j = 0; j < k; j++){
                    arr2[i][j] = *pointer;
                    pointer++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    else{
        printf("Couldn't find file.\n");
    }
}
```

Here is cp4in_1.txt:

```
ABCDE
PQRSTFG
acegikmoqsuwyz
bdfhjlnprtvx
```

The result I'm looking for should have arr2 contain an array of strings saying **"ABCDE"**, **"PQRSTFG"**, **"acegikmoqsuwyz"**, and **"bdfhjlnprtvx"**.

Answer (score 0):

you should always terminate your string with `\0` so:

```
          for (i = 0; i < 4; i++){
                for (j = 0; j < k; j++){
                    arr2[i][j] = *pointer;
                    pointer++;
                }
                arr2[i][j]='\0';
            }
```

also your program need a little change

```
int main()
{
    FILE* p;
    p = fopen("file.txt", "r+");

    int i = 0, j, k;
    char* pointer, lineRead[20], arr2[20][20];
    if (p != NULL)
    {
        while (!feof(p))
        {
            fscanf(p, "%s", &lineRead);
            for (k = 0; lineRead[k] != '\0'; k++);
            pointer = lineRead;
            for (j = 0; j < k; j++)
            {
                arr2[i][j] = *pointer;
                pointer++;
            }
            arr2[i][j] = '\0';
            i++;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            printf("%s\n", arr2[i]);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Couldn't find file.\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The biggest issue you are facing is trying to do *line-oriented* input with a *formatted-input* function. (and you are using it wrong) Using `fscanf` (the `scanf` family of functions) is full of pitfalls for the new C programmer. Until you know what they are, avoid using them and instead use the line-oriented input functions `fgets()` or POSIX `getline()` which ensure an entire line of input is consumed each time.

In your case, the array `lineRead` decays to a pointer on access, [C11 Standard - 6.3.2.1 Other Operands - Lvalues, arrays, and function designators(p3)](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.2.1p3), so your use of `&lineRead` is wrong (resulting in parameter for `fscanf()` having type `char **` instead of the correct `char*`). No `'&'` is required because `lineRead` is already a **pointer**, thus the correct use would be:

```
  while(fscanf(fin,"%19s",lineRead) == 1){
```

(**note:** you must also provide the *field-width* modifier to limit the read of characters to what will fit in `lineRead` -- including the *nul-terminating* character. Otherwise you use of `fscanf()` is no more secure than using `gets()` -- which has been removed from C11 completely)

That is just one of the many pitfalls waiting to bite you using the `scanf` family.

Instead, using a *line-oriented* input function, you can do:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define ROWS   20
#define COLS ROWS   /* if you need a constant, #define one (or more) */

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    char arr[ROWS][COLS];
    size_t n = 0;
    /* use filename provided as 1st argument (stdin by default) */
    FILE *fp = argc > 1 ? fopen (argv[1], "r") : stdin;

    if (!fp) {  /* validate file open for reading */
        perror ("file open failed");
        return 1;
    }

    /* while array not full, read line into array */
    while (n < ROWS && fgets (arr[n], COLS, fp)) {
        char *p = arr[n];           /* pointer to start of string */
        do {                        /* loop until '\n' found */
            if (*p == '\n')  
                *p = 0;             /* overwrite with nul-terminating char */
        } while (*p && *++p);
        n++;                        /* increment line counter */
    }

    if (fp != stdin)   /* close file if not stdin */
        fclose (fp);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++)  /* output stored lines */
        printf ("line %2zu : %s\n", i, arr[i]);
}
```

Using a line-oriented input function, the `'\n'` is read from input and included in the buffer filled. Your only job is to remove the trailing `'\n'` from the buffer. This is normally done with, e.g. `arr[n][strcspn(arr[n], "\n")] = 0;`, but since you cannot use `string.h` a simple loop will work just fine.

**Example Use/Output**

With your input file in `dat/cp4int_1.txt`, you would pass the filename to the program as it's first argument and receive the following output:

```
$ ./bin/readcp4int_1 dat/cp4int_1.txt
line  0 : ABCDE
line  1 : PQRSTFG
line  2 : acegikmoqsuwyz
line  3 : bdfhjlnprtvx
```

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem was that you were looping through arr[i] inside the while loop
And do not forget to place '\0' at the end of each string. Also, you were declaring char pointer several times inside the while loop, it is the error as well.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    FILE *fpin, *fpout;
    char lineRead[20], arr2[20][20], *pointer;
    int i = 0, j, k, len;


    fpin = fopen("cp4in_1.txt","r");
    if (fpin){
        while(fscanf(fpin,"%s", lineRead) != EOF){
        pointer = lineRead;
        for (k = 0; lineRead[k] != '\0'; k++);
        for(j = 0; j < k; j++){
            arr2[i][j] = *pointer;
            pointer++;
        }
        arr2[i][j+1] = '\0';//place zero char at the end of the string
        i++;
        if(i >= 4)
            break;
        }
    }
    else{
        printf("Couldn't find file.\n");
    }
    //output the result
    for(i = 0; i < 4; i++){
    printf("%s\n", arr2[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
ABCDE
PQRSTFG 
acegikmoqsuwyz
bdfhjlnprtvx
```